# Bake combined doesn't give me Normal information?

Tags: baking, normal-map

I might be confused when baking combined, all I got is this single image on top-left after baking, but where is the bluish Normal information in this image?

[image]

I might have misunderstood the combined baking, how can I got the normal information from this single combined image. As far as I know I can create low poly to bake normal from high poly, but when baking combined, if I do not have low poly, then what is the point that having **Normal Pass** in **Combined Bake** Type? Thanks a lot!